# Composer portable mode?

Tags: composer-php, portability

help me please:

**My case**

1. I have a manually mounted WAMP server using separate packages on drive E:
2. I did this, so that when I format my computer, I do not have to install it again.
3. For now everything works very well and little by little I have been making changes in the configurations to make tests.
4. Today I learned that there is "composer" which allows to manage dependencies for PHP projects.
5. I downloaded it and installed it (which is very easy).

**My question**

1. When formatting my computer and "reactivating" my WAMP, do I need to reinstall composer? Or can I use it as if it were portable?

Answer (score 0):

Composer is just a collection of PHP files, conveniently tied together in one file with the `.phar` file format (and probably with or without `.phar` extension). You should be able to either install Composer again, or download that Phar file again if it got lost.